# The 'offline_access' scope is not allowed when using OpenIdDict

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict, asp.net-core-5.0

Using Asp.Net Core 5.0 with Identity and OpenIdDict I have the following:

```
  services.AddOpenIddict()
  
    .AddCore(x => {
      x.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<Context>().ReplaceDefaultEntities<Application, Authorization, Scope, Token, Int32>();
    })

    .AddServer(x => {

      x.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
       .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
       .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
       .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

      x.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);

      x.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

      x.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate().AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

      x.UseAspNetCore()
       .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();

    })

    .AddValidation(x => {
      x.UseLocalServer();
      x.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

And I have the following client:

```
  OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor spa = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor {
    ClientId = "spa",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    ConsentType = OpenIddictConstants.ConsentTypes.Implicit,
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {
      new Uri("https://localhost:5002/oidc-signout")
    },
    RedirectUris = {
      new Uri("https://localhost:5002/oidc-signin"),
      new Uri("https://localhost:5002/oidc-silent-refresh")
    },
    Permissions = {
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
      OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api"
    },
    Requirements = {
      OpenIddictConstants.Requirements.Features.ProofKeyForCodeExchange
    }
  };
```

On the Angular Spa client application I am using the configuration:

```
const settings: UserManagerSettings = {
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  authority: "https://localhost:5000",
  client_id: 'spa',
  client_secret: 'secret',
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5002/oidc-signout",
  redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5002/oidc-signin",
  response_mode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
  silent_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5002/oidc-silent-refresh'
};
```

When I click on the SPA to login I am redirected and get the error:

```
The 'offline_access' scope is not allowed.
```

If I use it without 'offline_access' then everything works fine, e.g.:

```
scope: 'openid profile email api'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The refresh token flow should be enabled before the offline_access scope can be used.

In your `Startup.cs` you should change this line:
`x.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();`
into something like this:
`x.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().AllowRefreshTokenFlow();`

---

There's also a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/835) related to your problem.